# django: no module found named <app>.urls

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I am currently trying to develop a rather simple application using django, but I am stuck pretty much at the beginning: My project is named "kundencenter", my app is "customermgr".

Both, the project and the app have a `urls.py`, the project's `urls.py` includes the app's:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^customer/', include('kundencenter.customermgr.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But when I now try to access `customer/`, I am presented with an `ImportError`:

```
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named customermgr.urls
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
    ['/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
     '.',
     '/var/www/kundencenter',
     '/var/www']
```

As you can see, I've already gone nuts with the `PYTHONPATH`, but to no avail. As you might have guessed, the project is located in `/var/www/kundencenter`. I have also already checked that the `__init__.py` files were created, which they were (they are empty). The error appears when I run `manage.py runserver` and also using Apache with mod_wsgi.

I am pretty much at the end of my wisdom. Does anybody have any idea how I could get rid of this error?

Comment: Still happens to newcomers even 10 years later.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried without the project name ?

```
url(r'^customer/', include('customermgr.urls')),
```

instead of

```
url(r'^customer/', include('kundencenter.customermgr.urls')),
```

By the way, if it's not the case, import your models (or everything else) with the shortest path possible.
If you import models inside the same app, juste use "from models import X,Y,Z".

If you have to import models, functions, classes, whatever, from any other app, use "from my_other_app.models import X,Y,Z", but never include your project name.

If someday, you want to recycle your app for another django project, it will spare you some pain :)

Comment: I have tried that previously and just tried it again, the same error is produced. Thanks for the naming tip!

Comment: With Django 1.4, not including the project name will throw an error, so it all code must import the project, unless in a separate app not in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You should be building everything under a virtual env using PIP, including installing Django and all the other modules/libraries you need. Then you don't have to worry about messing with the Python path. Trying Googling for Python+Django+Virtualenv+PIP and read some of the recommended setups. It **really** does **simplify** the whole installation and configuring process, plus everything is self-contained and you can deploy easily using Fabric or some other deployment tool.

Good luck and I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a module/package installed somewhere else on your Python module search path of the same name that is being picked up first.

Add at the start of your WSGI script file:

```
import kundencenter
print kundencenter.__file__
```

and see where it gets picked up from.

Comment: The module is not found at all. I also tried

    import customermgr
    print customermgr.__file__

That module is also not found :-(

Answer (score 0):

Set your PYTHONPATH to:

```
['/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/var/www/kundencenter']
```

and urlpatterns to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^customer/', include('customermgr.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I don't know what is your directory structure, so this is my best gess.

Comment: Changing the `PYTHONPATH` as suggested unfortunately did not help, the same error is produced.

My directory structure is as follows:

    /var/www/kundencenter - here is manage.py
    /var/www/kundencenter/kundencenter - here is settings.py, wsgi.py, urls.py
    /var/www/kundencenter/customermgr - here is the other urls.py, as well as my models and my views

This is the structure as it was created by `manage.py startproject` and `manage.py startapp` of Django 1.4.

Comment: It is arguable that setting PYTHONPATH or sys.path explicitly to include internal directories of the Python installation is bad practice. If you are doing it, it would suggest you are doing something wrong to start with. In general you should rely on Python to get it right and not stuff with it.